# Exporting georeferenced image (jpeg, png) to .dxf file in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, export, dxf

Is it possible to export a georeferenced image, such as a jpeg with a world file, to a .dxf file using QGIS version 2.14.21?

The resulting .dxf file would only be the georeferenced image with no underlying information to be used as a basemap in another program. The dxf export option only allows vectors to be exported and I have not seen any plugins that would help. My company used a program that was able to do this but we no longer have access to it so I was wondering if this was possible in QGIS.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that raster layers are explicitly not supported in the dxf export function. See for example: https://www.qgis.ch/en/projects/dxf-export